# API Platform doesn't return the properties of the entities

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I'm using API Platform 2.7 for a very simple API; until now, I had a PoC that looked like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Entity\Embeddable\DbConfig;
use App\Entity\Embeddable\E1000Structure;
use App\Validator\Constraints AS PvetAssert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Softspring\DoctrineTemplates\Entity\Traits\AutoId;
use Softspring\DoctrineTemplates\Entity\Traits\TimestampMarks;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PlantRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="plant")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Cache(region="small_cache", usage="NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE")
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"App\Entity\EventListener\PlantCacheClearListener"})
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"plant:read"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"plant:write"}},
 *     attributes={"security_post_denormalize"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or (user != null and user.client == object.client)"},
 * )
 */
class Plant
{
    const MAP_LEVEL2_NO = 0 ; // No existe el mapa nivel 2
    const MAP_LEVEL2_TRACKERS = 1 ; // Nivel 2 representa trackers, los recuadros principales se buscarán mediante la columna TR
    const MAP_LEVEL2_STRINGBOXES = 2 ; // Nivel 2 representa stringboxes, los recuadros principales se buscarán mediante la columna SB

    const NO_OPTION = 0;
    const NORMAL = 1;
    const QUARTILE = 2;

    const TEN_MIN = 10;
    const FIFTEEN_MIN = 15;

    const STANDARD_WEEK = 0; 
    const AMERICAN_WEEK = 1;

    use AutoId;
    use TimestampMarks;
    use Traits\Key;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     *
     * @Groups({"plant:read", "plant:write"})
     */
    protected ?string $name = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="plants")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     *
     * @Groups({"plant:read", "plant:write"})
     * @ApiProperty(readableLink=false, writableLink=false)
     */
    protected ?Client $client = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false, length=100, options={"fixed":true})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     *
     * @Groups({"plant:read", "plant:write"})
     */
    protected ?string $timezone = null;

    [...]
}
```

This would return these three fields when requesting this resource; now I have removed the normalizationContext and denormalizationContext annotations from the class, and the ones on the fields thinking that this way it should return the entire entity (or at least try until it runs into a serialization issue), but it doesn't.
The response only includes:

```
    {
      "@id": "/api/plants/24",
      "@type": "Plant"
    },
```

Am I misunderstanding the [docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/v2.7/core/getting-started/)?

Comment: Do you have getters & setters for your entity ?

Comment: @DylanKAS yes, for all the important attributes.

Answer (score 0):

When you have no context groups in the operations, but the properties have groups its normal that they won't be serialized.

You have three options:

- add the groups to the operation's context
- remove all groups from the properties
- add the group "default" to the properties

PS: sometimes it's required to clear the cache to fix issues after changing annotations.

Comment: I removed the groups from the properties while keeping them for the class and I don't get any fields either.
According to the docs, the operations inherit the resource configuration, so the way I have it should be equivalent to defining the groups on the operations, right?

Comment: The only way I got it to work was by adding the groups to every property... -_-
What do you mean by the default group? A group with that name, or some other mechanism?
Also, do you know why the cache is not cleared as needed in the dev environment?

Comment: a group with the name 'default'